# How To Track Outbound Clicks On Banner Ads Without GA

Tags: analytics, links, tracking, click-tracking, awstats

I cannot use Google Analytics or other premium analytics tools. I can only use AWStats or internal tracking with a PHP script or something like that.

First attempt:

I have already read about how to track exit clicks with AWStats here: https://awstats.sourceforge.io/docs/awstats_extra.html#awredir However, the solutions requires me to install the `awredir.pl tool` and I'm worried it will effect my client's url.

Second attempt:

I found something along the lines of this:

```
<a href="http://www.advertisersite.com" onClick="parent.location='linktrack.php?id=advertiser'">
```

But, I'm not sure how to get the link tracking report. I didn't quite get if I should create a `linktrack.php` file and track how many hits go to that file.

If you guys know any efficient way to track outbound clicks without Google Analytics, that would be a big help.

Comment: You just need something that will register in your server logs.   The typical way we did it before GA was to use a redirector script on outbound links:  `<a href='/track.php?go=advertizesite.com'>`